# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. -- ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. --- thats the message return from console in my react app.

I don't understand why it returns this error when this is my code:

```
const Usuario = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get('/usuario').then((res) => { setUsers(res.data) })
    }, [])

    //console.log(users[0].perfil[0].departamento)
    return (
        <>
            <Header titulo={"Usuários"} />
            <Menu />
            <section>
                {users.map((user) => (
                    <div key={user.idUsuario}>
                        <h3>{user.idUsuario}   {user.nomeUsuario}</h3>
                        <p>E-mail:{user.emailUsuario}</p>
                        {user.perfil.map(perfis => (
                            <>
                                <div key={perfis.idPerfil}>
                                    <p>Perfil: {perfis.nomePerfil}</p>
                                </div>
                                {perfis.departamento.map(dep => (
                                    <div key={dep.idDepartamento}>
                                        <p>Departamento: {dep.nomeDepartamento}</p>
                                    </div>
                                )
                                )}
                            </>
                        )
                        )}
                    </div>
                )
                )}
            </section>

        </>
    )
}

export default Usuario;
```

I'm following the react documentation
(https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) , but I still keep taking that "Warning"

where am i making mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

This map:

```
{user.perfil.map(perfis => (
```

Has no `key` on its top-level child:

```
<>
  ...
</>
```

The element *immediately under* the top-level does, but that React Fragment element does not.

I don't think the short syntax for fragment elements supports attributes, but the longer explicit syntax does:

```
<React.Fragment key={perfis.idPerfil}>
  ...
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a key here:

```
{user.perfil.map(perfis => (
  <> /* ... */ </>
)}
```

Add a key

```
{user.perfil.map(perfis => (
  <React.Fragment key={perfis.id}> /* ... */ </React.Fragment>
)}
```